# sorting with collection class in Java not working

Tags: java, sorting, collections

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
   int g=0;int x=0;int y=0;
    List<Integer> temporaryOpenList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<ArrayList> listToSort = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=3 ; i>0 ; i--) {
        g = g + i;
        x = x + i;
        y = y + i;
        temporaryOpenList.add(g);
        temporaryOpenList.add(x);
        temporaryOpenList.add(y);
        ArrayList<Integer> openList = new ArrayList<Integer>(temporaryOpenList);
        temporaryOpenList.clear();
        listToSort.add(openList);
        System.out.println(listToSort);
   }
```

The output will be :

```
[[3, 3, 3]]  
[[3, 3, 3], [5, 5, 5]]  
[[3, 3, 3], [5, 5, 5], [6, 6, 6]]
```

Now I want to sort `listToSort` based upon g value means the 1st value of the value triplet `[g,x,y]`.But `collections.sort(listToSort)` command doesn't work

Comment: 3-5-6 This is already sorted nope ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but where did you get the idea that standard Java sorting supports sorting list of lists based on a first value of a triplet???

Comment: I suggest revising your title to focus on your task (sorting triplets within list) rather than complaining about `Collections.sort`.

Comment: Thank You all of you for your attention. I got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide your own Comparator:

```
Collections.sort(list1, (elem1, elem2) -> {
    return elem1.get(0).compareTo(elem2.get(0));
});
```

To make this compilable you have to change the declaration of `list1` to

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
```

I wrote that directly into the text editor in my browser, so if you find a typo, you can keep it ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use a clean comparator to sort your elements:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Collections;

public class MyClass {
public static void main(String args[]) {
   int g=0;int x=0;int y=0;
    List<Integer> temporaryOpenList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<List<Integer>> listToSort = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=3 ; i>0 ; i--) {
        g = g + i + 8; // i added 8 just for change 'g' value, to use it for sort
        x = x + i;
        y = y + i;
        temporaryOpenList.add(g);
        temporaryOpenList.add(x);
        temporaryOpenList.add(y);
        ArrayList<Integer> openList = new ArrayList<Integer>(temporaryOpenList);
        temporaryOpenList.clear();
        listToSort.add(openList);

   }

   Collections.sort(listToSort, new MyComparator());
   System.out.println(listToSort);
}
}




class MyComparator
    implements Comparator<List<Integer>>
{
    public int compare(List<Integer> list1, List<Integer> list2) {
        return list1.get(0).compareTo( list2.get(0));
    }
}
```

That works! but you should know that comparators are some of good things to use when you try to sort or compare objects.

Comment: Thank you . I subtract 3 from g for better understanding. It show that sorting is in ascending order. If I want to sort it in descending order what will I changed  in MyComparator class. Also this Comparator function is new to me. I don't understand the code.Can you suggest me a link other than the Java documentation from where I can learn it.

Comment: If you want to sort it in descending order you only need to change code to `return list2.get(0).compareTo( list1.get(0));` .  For more details about Java Comparator you can see [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_comparator.htm)

Comment: @Nomade alternatively just negate the result of `compareTo`, i.e. `return -list1.get(0).compareTo( list2.get(0));`

Comment: @Lothar, yes it is an other solution to get such result, but i would prefer to do it clean by using a function instead of `-` operator :
`return negate(list1.get(0).compareTo( list2.get(0)));`
Where `negate` is :
    `public int negate(value) { 
        return (value = -value);
    }`

Comment: @Nomade If clarity is your goal you can use `Collections.sort(listToSort, Collections.reverseOrder(new MyComparator()));`